# UnityでReadPixelsを使用しAndroidのスクリーンショットを撮り透過bmpを撮りたい。

Tags: unity3d

カメラのbackgroundのα値を０に設定し、下記のソースでAndroidで実行してもカメラのbackgroundが透過していないbmpが作成されます。
エディタで実行した際は、透過したbmpが保存出来ます。
どこを改善すれば、Androidでも透過で保存出来る様に出来るでしょうか？

```
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(256, 256, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, false);
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect( 0, 0, 256, 256), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();

    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    Destroy(tex);

    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytes);
```